# BPEL <switch> element not supported.

Tags: switch-statement, bpel

I get the following error when trying to use a `<switch>` element in BPEL.

```
BPEL element in namespace 
"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable" 
is not supported by this implementation.
```

Do I need to use something else instead? Was it removed from BPEL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<switch>` was part of BPEL 1.1 and has been removed in BPEL 2.0. The replacement is the `<if>` activity, which can be used as follows:

```
<if xmlns:inventory="http://supply-chain.org/inventory" xmlns:FLT="http://example.com/faults">
  <condition>
    bpel:getVariableProperty('stockResult','inventory:level') > 100
  </condition>
  <flow>
    <!-- perform fulfillment work -->
  </flow>
  <elseif>
    <condition>
      bpel:getVariableProperty('stockResult','inventory:level') >= 0
    </condition>
    <throw faultName="FLT:OutOfStock" variable="RestockEstimate" />
  </elseif>
  <else>
    <throw faultName="FLT:ItemDiscontinued" />
  </else>
</if>
```

(snippet is borrowed from the BPEL 2.0 spec)